# Looking for a plant that resembles a giant woody dandelion

Tags: identification, plant-recommendations

I used to have a plant growing in my backyard that resembled a seeding dandelion in the fall, but 3 feet tall. It had a single, straight, woody stem that I'm pretty sure was hollow. I think the spherical head was composed of many smaller flowers, but I also doubt it was an allium.

This was in Cincinnati, Ohio, but it may not have been native to the area; my mom could have planted it. (She doesn't remember it at all, now.)

Failing that, **what are some plants that resemble giant seeding dandelions?**

Comment: You say you don't think it's Allium, but it certainly could be, e.g., [*A. giganteum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium_giganteum) or cultivars like "Globemaster". What colour were the flowers or did you only see it when gone to seed? Perhaps a [milkweed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias), though has no resemblance in seed stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agapanthus as pictured in the other answer, or maybe an Eryngium variety, one of these is pictured below, there are other larger ones

http://peatfreeplants.org.uk/plants-for-sale/eryngium-planum/

Perhaps Echinops ritro

http://www.finegardening.com/small-globe-thistle-echinops-ritro

Or many of the alliums, which look like the one in the picture in the link below when fully dried out on the stem, with the seeds already dispersed

http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/2015/10/28/alliums-work-wonders-in-natural-settings

and like this before they dry out fully

https://thegardensmallholder.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/happy-new-year-2013/img_3774alliumpurplesensationseedheadsized/

There are other varieties - Allium christophii is a very large flower and seedhead.

Comment: Thanks for the name of the plant in my post, I didn't know the name of it

Comment: @AlexanderLeonVI - ok, well its Agapanthus, commonly known as African Lily or Lily of the Nile, depending where you live.

Comment: Maybe you're right, and it was an allium. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the plant that you are looking for is similar to this one:

[image][image]

Does it?

Thanks to @Bamboo for giving me this information that contains the name of the plant: "Agapanthus, commonly known as African Lily or Lily of the Nile, depending where you live ".

Comment: I have seen this plant in white and purple

Comment: Might help to post the name...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the name but know is posted in the bamboo's answer

Comment: It's close, but the spherical head was larger.